# Mounted S3 Drive via rClone Not Showing on SQL Server Management Studio as an Available Drive

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3, rclone

I have a mounted S3 bucket as Windows drive which was configured using rClone. I'm able to see the files that I needed including database back up files. I was actually thinking of leveraging a mounted S3 bucket as a source for when I restore database files locally since I do not have any other means of adding a disk drive on my machine. The free space which I currently have on my disk is only enough to accommodate restored database back up files. If I copy the file from S3, I will not have enough space to restore.

Unfortunately, while the mounted S3 bucket is available as a Windows disk drive, SQL Management Studio does not see it as an available drive. I've so far searched as to why this is the case and found that I needed to add NT Service\MSSQLSERVER user on the drive itself but every time I do it, it disappears after clicking OK. Is there a way for me to make this mounted s3 bucket as a source for when I restore database back up files?

Comment: How are you mapping the bucket with rclone? As with SMB/CIFS shares, drive mappings are typically only available to the users that make them. If you need all users to see them, including the MSSQLSERVER service account, the mapping needs to be performed by the SYSTEM account.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning - I used a local admin account. Does this mean that I need to use a different account to be able to do this?